# Error when trying to run rails server on OSX Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run rails server on OSX Yosemite and get this error:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/KirtMartin1/ruby/testlab/dosoon/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.

Kirts-MacBook-Pro-3:dosoon KirtMartin1$
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: kindly provide some information what you are tryign to do

Comment: Couple of items that might make it easier to get replies: how did you install ruby (and what version)? When you run the rails server command, are you somewhere inside your app's root directory (cannot tell from the code sample if that's the case or not, though it probably is)? Things like that ... as Panther noted (just saw his ... sorry), more details on your setup, issue, etc. help the community better supply answers or suggestions.